# Error: $controller:ctrlreg A controller with this name is not registered Service issue

Tags: angularjs

My application is executed successfully without `maninSvc.js`. After adding this file I'm seeing errror:

```
angular.min.js:123 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=MainController
at angular.min.js:7
```

My Code:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

  <link href="Scripts/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="Css/Shared.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="MainController.js"></script>
  <script src="mainSvc.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController as vm">

  <div data-ng-if="vm.success" class="success">{{vm.success}}</div>
  <div data-ng-if="vm.catch" class="catch">{{vm.catch}}</div>
  <div data-ng-if="vm.finally" class="finally">{{vm.finally}}</div>

</body>

</html>
```

MainController.js

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .controller('MainController', mainController);
  mainController.$inject = ['mainSvc'];

  function mainController(mainSvc) {
    var vm = this;
    mainSvc.getData()
      .then(function(data) {
      vm.success = "success";
    }).catch(function(response) {
      vm.catch = "catch";
    }).finally(function() {
      vm.finally = "finally";
    });
  }
})();
```

mainSvc.js

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .factory('mainSvc', mainSvc);
  mainSvc.$inject = ['$resource'];

  function mainSvc($resource) {
    var ResourceData = $resource({
      query: {
        isArray: true
      },
      get: {},
      save: {
        method: 'POST'
      },
      update: {
        method: 'PATCH'
      },
      put: {
        method: 'PUT'
      },
      remove: {
        method: 'DELETE'
      }
    });
    return {
      getData: getData,
    };

    function getData() {
      /// <summary>
      /// Gets Data
      /// </summary>
      return ResourceData
        .get()
        .$promise;
    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **`mainSvc.js`** should not have empty dependencies to the module, Then it will be considered as a new module. change it as

```
(function () {
    angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('mainSvc', mainSvc);
```

Comment: did you clear the cache and run the app? post the error

Comment: Yes,angular.min.js:123 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24resourceProvider%20%3C-%20%24resource%20%3C-%20mainSvc

Comment: your main service requires $resource so you need to add the reference for ng-resource

Comment: spent nearly fours hours debugging this and lastly found the answer here.